# NuGet in a project template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, projects-and-solutions

This question is about how to set up a project template to satisfy dependencies.

First, some context.

I have a MVC4/Durandal project that I'm trying to turn into a project template that distils all the goodness from a recent project, for re-use.

After creating a new project, adding all the non-standard good bits and shaking down the stub project so that it compiles and runs properly, I copied the project folder and plonked it on another computer with a freshly minted VS2013 installation, to see what broke.

The following were MIA:

- `Antlr.Runtime`
- `System.Net.Http.Extensions`
- `System.Net.Http.Primitives`
- `System.Web.Optimization`
- `WebActivator`
- `WebGrease`

There are a couple of issues making it less than obvious to me as to how I should proceed.

1. Installation of these things happened so long ago that I really couldn't say how they got onto my development workstation
2. In many cases package dependencies mean that installing one NuGET package will implicitly satisfy other dependencies
3. I don't know how set up a project template so that it causes NuGET package(s) to be installed

A bit of guidance would be appreciated, not to mention advice on best practice.

---

### Update

It appears there is direct NuGet support for project templates, I'm still [reading about it here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/07/08/project-templates-and-preinstalled-nuget-packages.aspx) and [also here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/packages-in-visual-studio-templates).

Since allowing NuGet to automatically resolve dependencies is a good way to ensure *compatible* versions are installed *in the right order*, the remaining question is **looking at the missing assemblies, how can I determine the most dependent package(s)?**

It seems that omitting the packages folder produces a slim template, and the projects produced therefrom install the missing files as soon as you start a build. That's good enough for me.

Comment: Some of those dependencies come from ASP.NET 4.5 not MVC. For project templates you may be looking at a list of automated NuGet packages.

Comment: Yes, I gathered it would be something like that. Could you be more specific as to how one goes about this?

Comment: OK, why has this question been voted down? If you examine the guide for asking questions it's practically a worked example of good practice. The absence of explanation makes it even less credible. It shows basic understanding, details efforts to resolve and has a clear definition of required outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply start with a blank ASP.NET 4.5 MVC project. The most basic dependencies should be satisfied then. NuGet has basic packages for Mvc and other packages you may need. NuGet packages are designed to self contain the missing assemblies they need. They'll get published in IIS when you deploy so you don't install anything on the server.